# What font is being used in this logo?

Tags: font-identification

what font is being used in this logo? I've been trying to find out all day. Thanks. :)

[image]

Comment: This sort of font is known as a "gothic" font. Use that keyword, and you should find something similar on the big font sites.

Comment: @confused That's not a gothic font. The term 'gothic' in typography typically refers to sans-serif faces (ala 'Franklin Gothic'). The term 'gothic script' is sometimes used to refer to blackletter ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackletter#The_name_Gothic )--however, this typeface isn't blackletter either. Blackletter is defined by the use of broad nibbed pens to create the strokes. This typeface uses standard serifs would would not have been created using broad nib calligraphy. I'd probably call that typeface an old-style serif face https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serif#Old-style

Comment: (Though I will admit certain characters *lean* towards script such as that lowercase 'a'. It's a bit of a mess in terms of style overall...which isn't that unusual for a freebie font)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name of the font is Phaistos Bold